# handling two way sockets efficiently in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a system core (server) that is to handle multiple connections and requests. Lets suppose my server has a client connected and is ready to communicate. My question here is, how would i make the server know that client wants to send some data or reversal. Since read blocks until it receives data... so how to manage between the read and write operations to sockets if we don't know what the remote system at other end expects?
I can see a way around it using multithreading. Any way around please???

Comment: You named it. Multithreading. One thread per socket, or even two.

Comment: [NIO in non-blocking mode](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/) provides an event based way where you can handle thousands of connections in a single thread. There are frameworks like [netty](http://netty.io/) based on it that you could probably use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multithreading is the only sensible way around this (in fact, it's one of the absolute classic cases where threading is required)  - you'll have to create a new thread for each connection.

You may wish to do this directly, or you may wish to use the constructs available in `java.util.concurrent` (which I'd recommend) - thread pools for instance. One sensible approach might be to use a [fixed thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) to make sure the number of threads doesn't grow too ridiculously large, and then spawn threads off there as required.